# Keyword domain pointing to main domain subdirectory (SEO)

Tags: seo

Keyword domain pointing to main site subdirectory

This one has always boggled me. Suppose one has a high ranking good DA domain. Say dog food or shirts. And there is a category page (subdirectory, landing page give it a name) for white shirts. `domain.com/whiteshirts`. And we would als own `whiteshirts.com` that has a 301 redirect to `domain.com/whiteshirts`.

Suppose we had 10 extra links that I dont know someone places or uses in an article to refer to us. Would it then help best to either:

- point the 10 links to `domain.com/whiteshirts`; or
- point the 10 links to `whiteshirts.com` with the 301

Keep in mind that the main domain already has authority, but wants to rank the landingpage better. So it is more like an what to do with additional links question.

Anyone have real experience with this one? Appreciate your feedback.

Comment: 301 passes juice, so both examples remain the same. Technically its best to point 10 links to sub folder rather than the domain because with any 301 you lose a small percentage of the juice.

Comment: Games/schemes with links, extra domains, and other stuff *will* degrade the effort that could simply be achieved with a directory. Google does tell us they use trust and authority caps as well as link evaluation and scoring so that for higher ranked sites, it is impossible to pass PR / # of links- it just plain does not work that way. Instead, it is authority cap * link score (which is less than 1). As well, Googles cluster and link analysis will detect this method and begin to downgrade scores.